# Working with getter and setter in c#

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and was wondering what I am doing wrong while working with get and set.

I have a VendingMachine that, when I input a number for the beverage that I want, it subtracts from the total.

```
private int _coke = 2;
public int Beer = 20;
public int LemonLime = 20;
public int Grape = 20;
public int CreamSoda = 20;
public bool AnohterBevrage;
```

The problem is that it keeps subtracting even after it reaches 0. Well, there cant be -1 Coke left in the Machine. So, I tried this.

```
 public int Coke
    {
        get => _coke;
        set
        {
            if (_coke == 0)
            {
                _coke = value;
                Console.WriteLine("No more Coke Left!");
            }
        }

    }
```

But it doesn't work, so I'm not sure where I'm getting stuck. I'm not sure if the Math function is relevant here.

If there is something missing, let me know. I will try and adjust. This getter and setter gets me all confused.

EDIT: Add function

```
public void Math()
    {
        var input = Console.ReadKey();

        while (input.Key == ConsoleKey.D1)
        {
            do
            {
                _coke--;
                Console.WriteLine("\nTotal Coke Left: " + Coke);

                Console.Write("\nWould You like Another Bevrage ?y/n: ");

                if (Console.ReadLine() == "y")
                {
                    AnohterBevrage = true;
                    Content();
                    Math();  
                }
                else
                {
                    AnohterBevrage = false;
                }
                break;

            } while (AnohterBevrage == true); 
        }       
    }
```

Comment: You should probably avoid writing to the console in a property setter.

Comment: Why is that.. ?

Comment: Just a general guideline, but it's because it imposes a UI side effect on the client of your class. Normally UI is not tightly bound to classes like that. The client of the class determines what to write to the user if a property has a specific value. Just something to think about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start trying to do something, you need to build a model of what you are doing.  Using getters/setters as your UI is not a great design (as @Rufus L pointed out).  Instead, picture a Coke machine in your head.  There are racks of various drinks (that get restocked), and then a mechanical system that implements a user interface that allows someone to pick a drink and get it delivered.  You should separate your design into those two parts.

One hint that your design needs work is that your main function (that's doing all the work) is named "Math".  If you were to look at this code in two months, you'd see "Math" and not have a clue it represented a Coke machine.

I wrote a quickie coke machine that matches your needs (well, I think it does).  It uses that same mental model, a set of beverage racks and a controller.  I did this with a simple class that represents a rack of drinks and a controller written in a console app's main routine (so everything is static).

The RackOfBeverage class (it includes a restock method that's never called):

```
class RackOfBeverages
{
    public string Label { get; }
    public int Count { get; private set; }

    public RackOfBeverages(string label, int initialCount)
    {
        Label = label;
        Count = initialCount;
    }

    public void Restock(int howMany)
    {
        Count += howMany;
    }

    public bool Dispense()
    {
        if (Count > 0)
        {
            --Count;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool IsEmpty => Count <= 0;  //a read-only property
}
```

It has a label (indicating what kind of drink it is), an inventory/count and a `Dispense` method.  The Dispense call will return false if there are no drinks left.

Then I wrote a simple controller (as the Main method in a console app along with a few other bits that I put in the Program class):

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, RackOfBeverages> Beverages =
        new Dictionary<string, RackOfBeverages>
        {
            {"COKE", new RackOfBeverages("Coke", 2)},
            {"SPRITE", new RackOfBeverages("Sprite", 20)},
            //etc.
        };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the machine\r\nType a selection (type \"Exit\" to quit)");
        while (true)
        {
            var selection = Console.ReadLine();
            //did the user enter the name of a drink
            if (Beverages.Keys.Contains(selection, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                var beverage = Beverages[selection.ToUpper()];
                //was there enough to dispense a drink
                if (beverage.Dispense())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Here's your {beverage.Label}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Sorry, no {beverage.Label} for you");
                }
            }
            //or, perhaps, the user chose to exit the app
            else if (selection.ToUpper() == "EXIT")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exiting");
                break;
            }
            //finally, if the user didn't enter anything I understand 
            //let him/her know and then let him/her try again
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Pick a valid selection");
            }

        }
        
    }
}
```

Separating out the "concerns" in an application is important.  Here, the UI is completely separate from the beverage storage.  If you want to add another beverage, just add it to the Dictionary up at the top, and the UI will continue to function with the old beverages and the new beverage you added.

Comment: Thank you very much, this acctualy was really informative.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (_coke == 0)
```

You're checking the *current* value.

That means that you can only set the property if it is currently `0`.

Comment: Well yeah, the current value will be 0, after i selected 2 times coke. I added the function... Maybe im understanding wrong. My englisch skill are not the best when it comes to coding.

Comment: @MewTwo: No; this means the current value _before_ you set it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want this code, If `_coke` less than `0` show message ,otherwise subtract `_coke` value.

```
public int Coke
{
    get { return _coke; }
    set
    {
        if (_coke <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No more Coke Left!");

        }
        else
        {
            _coke = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is my output... im not sure what im doing wrong. https://gyazo.com/15357ab21523041bc823858f0178642a

Comment: You can try to add this on set condition `if (_coke <= 0 && (_coke - value) >= 0)` @MewTwo